# Unexplained number in front of json array from php json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to create a `JSON Array` of objects in php with `json_encode`.
The source of the Jobs Array is Doctrine but I think that is unimportant.

```
$jobsAsArray = array();
foreach ($jobs as $job) {
    $jobsAsArray[] = array('jobId' => $job->getId(),
                    'jobName' => $job->getName(),
                    'jobType' => $job->getJobType());
}
echo json_encode($jobsAsArray);
```

I get this result:

```
1[{"jobid":1,"jobName":"Name1","jobType":"type1"},{"jobid":2,"jobName":"CoolName","jobType":"type2"},{"jobid":3,"jobName":"noName","jobType":"noType"}]
```

If I understood correctly, I get an JSON Array with three objects. But I don't understand why there is a '1' in front if the Array.

thank you in advance

Comment: you have another echo or print in your script.

Comment: insufficient infos; provide more snippet of code

Comment: somwhere in the same script some line prints 1 as a result of something. find each print/echo and examine

Comment: Thx Amani! There was another echo! I searching at the wrong spot all the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved in Comments! There was another echo in my script.

`you have another echo or print in your script. – Amani'

thx!

Answer (score 0):

Where you show the json array, are you sure you didn't put this number accidentally before the result? if not, can you post the rest of the code like html and the rest of php? it's weird x)